# Cocoa NIB: Custom EN Localisation

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, localization

At the moment I'm busy localising an app which I've written for a friend. It works perfectly in the various translations. What I'm trying to find out is how to implement a 'custom' localisation. As an example, say we have en_US and en_US_Slang, how would I add the latter to the list of localisations or under NSLocalisedString?

To explain the situation, This guy was running 2 separate applications to keep information for his band. One was MS Access based and the other Filemaker Pro based (go figure?!)

Various members of the band either use on, or the other. He is the only one that uses both as he designed them both.

At the moment, when you fire the app up (Mac App not iOS), it asks you whether you were a FMP or Access user previously.

Based on this, the localised strings revert to the terminology used in the various apps.

i.e in MSAccess, a band gig location was called "Function Premises" whereas in FMP the same was called "Gig Location". To avoid having to retrain all of them (as I'm doing it free of charge due to them doing a freebie birthday gig for me), I thought the quickest way was to keep the labels they are used to, all the same.

From what I can work out it's:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"en_Access"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

and

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"en_FMP"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Can someone confirm this or possibly point me in the right direction (maybe some apple docs?) as I'd prefer to find out before I delve into the issue :)

Thanks

A

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, your idea here is to define your own locales (en_Access and en_FMP) in order to get differentiated strings. I don't believe you can do this on Mac OS X (or iOS), as the system will only recognise locale identifiers that it knows to be valid.

Anecdotally, you can create custom locales on Microsoft Windows as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317785%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But not Mac OS X.

Comment: Whats another way around that? I'm trying to avoid double coding everything with if statements all over the show :D

Comment: There are various options. No if statements all over the place but a replacement of the NSLocalizedString calls with your own implementation. It could be a new method with an extra parameter or two different methods or an OO approach (e.g. defining a LocalizedStringProvider class and have two different instances of it, one for the old terminology and one for the newer one)